# Change the value of a declared variable based on the condition of a column while querying in MS SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, gaps-and-islands

I am really sorry for NOT stating the problem clearly. The older problem was very vague as suggested by many members. So I have removed it and now laying out the actual problem in much clearer way.

## Edit:

Below is the table I am working with:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl
(
  Start_Date date NOT NULL,
  End_Date date NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO tbl (Start_Date, End_Date)
VALUES 
  ('2015-10-01', '2015-10-02'),
  ('2015-10-02', '2015-10-03'),
  ('2015-10-03', '2015-10-04'),
  ('2015-10-13', '2015-10-14'),
  ('2015-10-14', '2015-10-15'),
  ('2015-10-28', '2015-10-29'),
  ('2015-10-30', '2015-10-31');
```

Consecutive Start_Date (i.e with difference of exactly 1 day) should be one category. So, I need to create a variable called Category with value 1 for Start Date 2015-10-01 to 2015-10-03, with value 2 for Start Date 2015-10-13 to 2015-10-14, value 3 for Start Date 2015-10-28, and value 4 for Start Date 2015-10-30.

#### My Approach:

I am trying to create a variable called @cnt = 0, and increment it by 1 when DATEDIFF(DAY, Start_Date, LAG(Start_Date)) <> 1, otherwise keep it same.

```
DECLARE @CNT INT = 0;

SELECT Start_Date, End_Date, (CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY, Start_Date, 
LAG(Start_Date, 1)) <> 1 THEN @cnt = @cnt + 1 ELSE @cnt END) AS Category
FROM tbl;
```

Apparently I cannot increment @cnt = @cnt + 1 inside the query like that. Getting an error: Incorrect syntax near '='.

My question is there any way I can change the value of a declared variable (like @cnt) based on the condition of a column in the table and output the changed value in the same table?

Comment: I get the sense you may be looking for one of the window functions.  Sample data and desired results would be more helpful

Comment: Not clear to me what you want to do.

Comment: This feels like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). What are you trying to accomplish with that @count variable?

Comment: I am sorry for not being clear. The details of the actual problem has been put now.

Comment: You are looking in the wrong direction.  You don't need to use a variable to solve this.   This is a classic gaps and islands problem.   Google `SQL Gaps and Islands` and you will find numerous solutions.

Comment: @TabAlleman Thank you so much for guiding me in proper direction. That surely helps. Although still wondering out of curiosity if the value of a declared variable can be changed dynamically based on the condition of the query?

Comment: What happens when you try the query in my answer?

Comment: @TabAlleman It throws an error: "A SELECT statement that assigns a value to a variable must not be combined with data-retrieval operations". If I put the CASE statement in parenthesis and AS Category then it says: Incorrect syntax near '='.

Comment: Ok, in that case the second part of my answer applies.   The only way to do this is in a separate query.

Answer (score 1):

Since it seems you are doing this to fill a column, why not just use a query to get that column?

```
--sample data
if object_id('tempdb..#x') is not null drop table #x
CREATE TABLE #x (A VARCHAR, B VARCHAR)
INSERT INTO #x (A,B) VALUES
('A', 'X'),
('B', 'Y'),
('C', 'X'),
('D', 'Y'),
('E', 'X'),
('F', 'X'),
('G', 'Y')


-- get count column
if object_id('tempdb..#y') is not null drop table #y
SELECT A, B,
    CASE WHEN B = 'X' THEN
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY B)
                ELSE 0
    END AS Count_Tracker
INTO #y
FROM #x
ORDER BY A

SELECT A,B,
     CASE WHEN Count_Tracker=0 THEN LAG(Count_Tracker,1,0) OVER(ORDER BY A) ELSE Count_Tracker END AS CountCol
FROM #y
ORDER BY A
```

output

```
*A* *B* *CountCol*
A    X   1
B    Y   1
C    X   2
D    Y   2
E    X   3
F    X   4
G    Y   4
```

Answer (score 0):

Well this would solve your syntax problem, but I don't know if it would produce the results you are after, since I know nothing about your tables, data, expected results, or the "bigger query" that this will be a part of; try it and see:

```
SELECT A,  @count = CASE WHEN B = 'X' THEN @count + 1 ELSE @count END
```

The safest way to do this is probably by setting the value of `@count` in its own query.

Comment: I am sorry for the confusion. I have stated the actual problem in much clearer way now.